# I'm doing my first ever jQuery and getting told it's not a defined function

Tags: php, jquery

Trying to use this code to change content on a page without reload. It's my first time playing with jQuery.

I keep getting this error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: swapContent is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onmousedown*

This is the code:

```
    <script type="/text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="/text/javascript">
        function swapContent(cv){
            "use strict";
            $("#myDiv").html("").show();
            var url="main_views.php";
            $.post(url, {contentVar: cv},function(data){
                $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It's actioned by these buttons:

```
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">View One</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">View Two</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con3');">View Three</button>
```

and it references this file `main_views.php`

```
<?php

$contentVar=$_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar=="con1"){
echo "<p>Stuff</p>";
} else if ($contentVar=="con2"){
echo "<p>Other Stuff</p>";
} else if ($contentVar=="con3"){
echo "<h1>Yet more stuff</h1>";
}

?>
```

I was following [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CMTQtnZ0G0) to learn it. It is a 2011 video, so I'm wondering if the script is incorrectly formatted?

Have compared mine to the video several times. Have also tried some code checkers to no luck.

Have used the most current `jquery 3.6.3` and the same one as the tutorial `jquery-1.5.1`

Cannot work out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you ensured your script tags are in the <head> </head> tags? Else include swapcontent within document ready jquery

Comment: Not just about the problem, but you don’t need the `javascript:` in front of the function name for the “on” events.

Comment: `language="JavaScript"`? can you try to put your code in a simple `<script>/*code here*/</script>`? I can't say for sure but since your problem is your function is not defined in the global scope, it means that script is involved

Comment: Also, although there’s nothing wrong with jQuery, in 2023 I’d personally tell you to look into just regular JavaScript and AJAX/fetch

Comment: Neither the `language` nor the `type` attribute need to be set anymore, JavaScript won the wars so they are the default. Your `type` is actually incorrect because it should not have the leading `/`

Comment: You can see the difference between your code and the tutorial at: `1:25` https://youtu.be/0CMTQtnZ0G0?t=85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to replicate the issue: it's the `type="/text/javascript"` that is incorrect.

This needs to be changed (or just removed) on both/all `<script>` tags.  In the "not working" example, you don't get an error on jquery as it doesn't get to the `$` line, but fixing your `<script>` tag that has your script then gives `$ is not defined` as the `<script src=jquery` line also needs fixing.

Not working:

```html
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">View One</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">View Two</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con3');">View Three</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="/text/javascript">
        function swapContent(cv){
            "use strict";
            $("#myDiv").html("test:"+cv).show();
            // ajax/php not relevant to the question as it doesn't get that far
        }
    </script>
```

Working:

```html
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">View One</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">View Two</button> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
<button href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con3');">View Three</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function swapContent(cv){
            "use strict";
            $("#myDiv").html("test:"+cv).show();
            // ajax/php not relevant to the question as it doesn't get that far
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

various things:

1 - the `type="/text/javascript"` is wrong. u can remove it as the default is `"application/javascript"`, that is what you want

2 - remove the "javascript:" part on the `onmousedown` handler. also remove the `href` on the button, which is not a valid attribute on a button. also remove the `onClick` (which is actually `onclick` but maybe that's actually the event u want to use?!) and just add `type="button"`.